# How to determine an Overflow in a 4 bit ripple-carry adder-substractor?

Tags: boolean, integer-overflow

[image]

What function that depends by following variablesc (First Operand's sign[0/1], Second Operand's sign[0/1], Result's sign[0/1] and Operation sign[0/1]) can identify an overflow in the  4-bit ripple-carry adder/substractor?

P.S. 
    An overflow occurs only if:

- the sum of two positive numbers yields a negative result, the sum has overflowed.
- the sum of two negative numbers yields a positive result, the sum has overflowed.

I only know the method with checking the 2 last carries but it seems that there's another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PS already contains the correct logic formula written in prose (for addition). Remember that a number is "positive" if its sign bit is zero and the number is negative if its sign bit is one.<sup>1</sup> This means you can translate "yields a negative result" to "the operation sign is 1". You can translate the other statements about operands or results to logic conditions in the same way, to finally derive a general boolean formula.

---

1: I know that zero is neither positive nor negative, but treating zero as positive does no harm in this case.